# Removing gap between historical and forecasted in autoplot from forecast package

Tags: r, ggplot2, forecast, autoplot

```
?autoplot.forecast
If showgap=FALSE, the gap between the historical observations and the forecasts is removed.
```

However, for me it is not removed.

```
library(forecast)

d <- ts(rnorm(36), start = c(2021, 1), frequency = 12)

fc <- snaive(d, h = 12)

autoplot(fc, showgap = FALSE)
```

Using `plot` works fine however

```
plot(fc, showgap = FALSE)
```

Comment: Probably a `ggplot2` bug. Why not just use `plot`, looks better anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, I originally thought this was a bug in the `forecast::autoplot()` function, but it turns out it is not.  The function `plot.forecast()`, which is run when you use `plot()` on a `'forecast'` object, contains the `showgap=` argument.  The command `?autoplot.forecast` does indicate the `showgap=` argument, but not for `autoplot()` - it's for the `plot.forecast()` function.

The good news is that there appears to be a method within `autolayer(...)` that contains this argument and you can use it.  i.e. check the help again for `plot.forecast()` a bit lower and you'll see this:

```
## S3 method for class 'forecast'
autolayer(object, series = NULL, PI = TRUE, showgap = TRUE, ...)
```

We can use `autolayer()` in concert with `autoplot()`.  So, this seems to work:

```
autoplot(fc) + autolayer(fc, showgap = F)
```

[image]